# Multilanguage webpage: How can i get user language/locale in one easy and reliable step?

Tags: php, facebook, geolocation, multilingual, ip

I just started developing a **multilingual webpage** which site users can **read and post entries without registration**. (It's based on Facebook "like button" and "comment social plugin".)

In most case i use *[Hostip.info](http://www.hostip.info/)* to get users language from their ip (based on location) but it's not enought good. In other case i must relies on browsers language (because of unlocated ip address).

I must find a reliable way to decide where my users come from and what language they are speak. **I'll be thankful if somebody can help me.**

(Temporary i solved the problem with a popup alert box which everybody can set their own locale. In the near future i want just a simple warn that says "You speak english. It's right?")

Comment: Browser language is usually the way to go. Is that not good enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request http header should have a "Accept-Language" which you can try and use.  I would suggest setting a cookie on the user's preference so that they do not keep getting a different language if they are visiting a foreign country for argument sake.

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"];
$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET"];
```